# Jenkins Pipeline: checking if file was changed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I plan to add Release Notes to the git repository for our software and want to deliver the Artefact only if the Release Notes where changed.

My Question is is there a way to check if RN are changed since the last release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to determine if a file has changed since some other commit:

1. If you use GitHub, it has API for "compare". You need to ask using current commit ID and the commit ID you have for "last release", whatever it is.
2. Regardless of whether you use GtHub or not, plain `git` can give you the answer if you examine the output of `git diff --name-only`. For that, you would need the same two commit IDs.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something like this.

The pipeline will run if there is any change on ReleaseNotes.txt file in the SCM.

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('run with condition') {
            when {
                when { changeset "ReleaseNotes.txt" }
            }
            steps {
                echo "I will Run If the ReleaseNotes.txt was changed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will run once, and only once, for each commit to that file. It will _not_ run in the next build. Changesets are just that: what has changed since the last build.